# implicit declaration of function 'lseek64' is invalid in C99

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I have got the following compile error while compiling the [FFmpeg-Vitamio](https://github.com/yixia/FFmpeg-Vitamio.git).

My OS is **Mac OS X 10.10.9**

NDK version: **android-ndk-r10d**

Gcc version:

```
$gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.1
Thread model: posix
```

Error message:

```
libavformat/fd.c:59:9: error: implicit declaration of function 'lseek64' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    return lseek64(fd, pos, whence);
```

Comment: So you are compiling on the Mac using Mac command line tools, how is it related to Android?

Comment: @AntonSavin Because it clearly relates to the android NDK. Please read the question

Comment: @AntonSavin Maybe the Gcc version: is confused. Yes, As Ed George said, I use the NDK r10d.

Comment: Then please post exact command line which compiles `fd.c`. What you posted about gcc version is unrelated to the question because it's not the compiler which is used to compile for android NDK.

Comment: The point is, `lseek64` function is present in Android NDK but it's not present in MacOS (try to find it in `/usr/include`). So you are most likely using the wrong tool.

Comment: @AntonSavin arm-linux-androideabi-gcc

Comment: @JerikcXIONG *full command line* with all options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a linux system, use:

```
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE     /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

to have a proper prototype for lseek64

I'm  not sure how this will relate to the mac OS and using the arm-linux-antroideabi-gcc tool

Answer (score 0):

@anton is right.

Wrong gcc is used,

```
${NDK_HOME}/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
```

is supposed to used